# Using Singularity with LibSass

Tags: singularitygs

is there any thing I can do to help with this? Any tips on where to start looking? Singularity works fine with LibSass - until debug mode is turned on at which point it generates Bus error: 10 (using grunt).

https://github.com/at-import/Singularity/issues/215